# "Enable foldable display" not showing even if updated android studio to version 3.5 and updated android emulator to 29.1.12

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

Can anyone tell me why I'm unable to see the "Enable foldable display" option in my emulator settings?

First of all, let me give you the link that describes "How to setup foldable emulator?"
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/04/emulator-2901-canary.html

**Above link has the screenshot attached below where you can see the highlighted portion that describes "Enable foldable display" option:**
[image]

**Own emulator settings screenshot which does not give me the "Enable foldable display" option.**

[image]

**Below are the attached screenshots where you can see that I have updated all the things which required for foldable emulators:**

*Updated android studio screenshot*
[image]

*Screenshot while updating the android emulator*
[image]

*Below are the two foldable screenshots but where you can see that it is not auto-adjusting itself.*
[image][image]

*Below is the final un-foldable screenshot*
[image]

If I'm trying to fold/unfold device than the device is folding/unfolding properly but the graphics part remains to be same. so I guess the issue is of "Enable foldable display" option. so can any help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
So i installed the canary version of android studio https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Unistalled the emulator from the sdk manager of android studio and re-installed it.

Now it works!